# ROS parameters - understanding of a line code

Tags: ros, parameters, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I found a code on the internet about SLAM and i'm not able to make it function. I need to understand what those code line do:

```
     std::string transport;
  std::string depth_topic;
  if(!nh.getParam("depth_topic",depth_topic))
  {
     depth_topic = "camera/depth_registered/image_raw";
     ROS_INFO_STREAM("Could not retrieve depth_topic param");
  }
  if(!nh.getParam("depth_image_transport",transport))
  {
    transport = "compressedDepth";
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("could not retrieve depth_image_transport param");
  }
```

Because when i run the code i have all the INFO messages displayed on my terminal, so it means that it doesn't find topics from my camera.
Indeed, on the book "a gentle introduction to ROS", they write the following sentence: The get function returns true if the value was read successfully and false if there was a problem, usually indicating that the requested parameters has not been assigned a value"

Does the code assume that we have a yaml file ? if not, how i can avoid this message, that is to say return true at the line nh.etParam.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205839/ros-parameters---understanding-of-a-line-code/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the parameters `depth_topic` and `depth_image_transport` on the [Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) (also see [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters).

The exact name depends on whether the node handle `nh` is a private node handle or not. Private node handles are initialized like this:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
```

... whereas the global node handle lacks the `"~"`.

Assuming `nh` is a private node handle, and your node is called `my_node`, the full name of the parameters are `/my_node/depth_topic` and `/my_node/depth_image_transport`. You need to set these to the names of the topics you want to use. You can use either the `rosparam` command line tool before starting your node, set the parameters in the launch file, or add them to the `rosrun` call (just search for these things on the wiki). Use `rosparam dump FILENAME.yaml` to inspect the parameters currently stored on the parameter server and `rostopic list` to see what topics are advertised.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-03-25**:
Thank for your answer Martin. The node is not private. So in the code i did the following stuff for example: nh.setParameters("depth_topic","/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"); I have no more the INFO message. But tell me if i'm mistaken, in the code, if the parameter is not set

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-03-25**:
, for example the depth_topic one, depth_topic = "camera/depth_registered/image_raw"; this part do that stuff that is to say initialize the parameter ? What does the line do in this case ?

Because Depth_topic is nowhere is the code. That's why i'm a bit confused.

I did all the tutorials.